# Simple for loop is throwing me for a loop - decimal increment error

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting a simple for loop but getting odd results. I'm incrementing by a decimal (.02) but it seems to be adding incorrectly.

here is the loop:

```
for ( var a = 0; a <= 10; a += .02 ) {

    console.log(a);

}
```

the results are fine for a bit..

```
0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1
```

then it gets a little strange:

```
0.12000000000000001
```

and then it gets really far out:

```
0.19999999999999998 ... 9.999999999999876
```

Aside from the odd decimal addition it stops short of my end goal of 10.

I've tried `for (var a = 0; a <= 10; a = (Math.round(a * 100)/100) + .02 )` (which gets me closest but still runs odd), parsefloating a, even a += 2/100.

Same results in a while loop.

Any ideas would be great!

EDIT: Although there are some workarounds for floating point precision in this post "[How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)" - I'm not sure how many would fit elegantly in a loop construct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toFixed(2)`

```js
for ( var a = 0; a <= 10;) {
    console.log(a);
    a += 0.02;
    a = +a.toFixed(2)
}
   
// Another possible way is
var limit = 10;
var increment = 0.02;
for ( var a = 0; a <= limit * 100; a += increment * 100) {
    console.log(a / 100);
}
```

Comment: Works for me.  Thanks!

Comment: @logic8 Glad to help :)